# Are questions following the pattern "[noun] + how + [adjective] + ...?" correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the word order "[noun] + how + [adjective] + ...?" in a question acceptable? By that, I mean questions as:

- An object how big could fit through that hole?
- Questions how serious may be asked?

Such a pattern seems strangely familiar to a foreigner, but I could not pinpoint any reasonable examples from across the Internet at the moment.

If such an expression is obnoxiously incorrect to native English speakers, can you come up with any elegant periphrastic constructions? "How big of an object...?" and "How big is an object that...?" seem to be reasonable ones.

Comment: I would say "How big an object...?" The other one is more difficult. I think we would have to say "How serious are the questions that may be asked?"

Comment: "how + [adjective] + of + a/n + [noun]" is distinctively American-sounding; in UK-ish at least we'd just say, eg, "how big an object" as @KateBunting says; never "how big of an object".

Your asterisked *"How big an object could fit through that hole?" doesn't need an asterisk at all.  It is absolutely fine!  Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: "How serious questions will be asked?" is definitely not fine to my ears!  "Questions HOW serious will be asked?" would be passable in very casual speech.  In such speech you might also hear "an object how big?!", but almost never with a long string of words after it, as in your first example.

I wouldn't say they're obnoxiously incorrect, but they're all jarring.  I'd say: "How big an object could fit through that hole?", "How serious are the questions that will be asked?".

Comment: Thank you for your contributions. I find it quite intriguing (and confusing at the same time) that "How big (of) an object..." seems correct, but "How serious (of) questions..." does not. Maybe it is some sort of a peculiar collocation that only applies to physical dimensions?

Comment: Interesting question!  I'm not sure what the reasoning is, let's see... "How angry a customer did you serve?", "How good a soldier are you?" are both fine.  Indeed, "how serious a question did you ask?" is also OK.  I think it's just that you have to have an indefinite article (and a singular noun) in this form.

Comment: You can see something perhaps similar, but using the definite article (which can be a plural), in the archaic/poetic form like: "how dark the night we parted", "how broken the remnants of my work"; or even some other determiner, as in "how glad my heart when I see you".  But all of these are not questions, but emphatic statements.